# Number of decimal digits in converted latitude/longitude values (with Location.convert method)

Tags: java, android, decimal, latitude-longitude, approximation

I am trying to create a converter utility for latitude/longitude coordinates.

Please look at this code snippet:

```
    ...
    //at this point the location variable has valid location information

    String latDegrees = Location.convert(location.getLatitude(), Location.FORMAT_DEGREES);
    String longDegrees = Location.convert(location.getLongitude(), Location.FORMAT_DEGREES);

    String latMinutes = Location.convert(location.getLatitude(), Location.FORMAT_MINUTES);
    String longMinutes = Location.convert(location.getLongitude(), Location.FORMAT_MINUTES);

    String latSeconds = Location.convert(location.getLatitude(), Location.FORMAT_SECONDS);
    String longSeconds = Location.convert(location.getLongitude(), Location.FORMAT_SECONDS);


    Log.d("results ","lat "+location.getLatitude());
    Log.d("results ","long "+location.getLongitude());
    Log.d("results ","lat degrees "+latDegrees);
    Log.d("results ","long degrees "+longDegrees);
    Log.d("results ","lat min "+latMinutes);
    Log.d("results ","long min "+longMinutes);
    Log.d("results ","lat sec "+latSeconds);
    Log.d("results ","long sec "+longSeconds);
    ...
```

I get this kind of strings

```
results: lat aa.4919783
results: long bb.3432917
results: lat degrees aa.49198
results: long degrees bb.34329
results: lat min aa:29.5187
results: long min bb:20.5975
results: lat sec aa:29:31.12188
results: long sec bb:20:35.85012
```

(where I concealed the first two digits with letters)

As you can see,

-the original values have 7 decimal digits

-the degrees have 5

-the minutes have 4

-the seconds have 5

Is it correct?
Can those strings be used where latitude and longitude are needed as a parameter?
Is that a standard form, or other decimals could be necessary?

Comment: The primitive type `double` has a higher precision, so you should work with `double` especially as the math relates to a plane on a 3D depressed globe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location#FORMAT_DEGREES), all converted results have 5 decimal digit max. If decimal end with one or several 0 digit, they will be ignored, so converted results can have less than 5 decimal digit.

The original value is a Double, so it doesn't have fixed decimal digits

Comment: So why do minutes have 4, maybe the fifth digit is 0?

Comment: This is because this function is implemented using DecimalFormat("###.#####") for conversion (See android source: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/location/java/android/location/Location.java). Yes, the fifth digit is 0.

Comment: Is it also possible that the number is an integer with no decimal digits and no dot, like 20 ?